# How to not change the keys while renewal for SSL pinning mechanism

Tags: apache, ssl, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, certbot

I have installed LetsEncrypt on Ubuntu 16.04 Apache server. It generated 4 .pem files under its letsencrypt/live directory. I am using the public and certificate pinning mechanism and dumping them into the iOS app bundle. To avoid updating the app on renewal i have read that it has to be renewed using a --csr flag but couldn't get much help on this. Can letsencrpyt renew the way i want to or i need to use some other client? Do i have to regenerate all the certs as am sure it generated only pem and no csr files while creating certificates with Letsncrypt. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The csr generated by LE can be found out in /etc/letsencrypt/csr. I picked the latest csr file (usually the one which has the highest integer is the latest, e.g.: 0005_csr-letsencrypt.pem will be latest to 0004) and renewed the certificate with the above command:

```
letsencrypt certonly —csr /etc/letsencrypt/csr/0005_csr-letsencrypt.pem
```

This will generate 3 files called in the same directory:

```
000x_chain.pem - has same PubKey but new expiry (what we need)
000x_chain.pem - has some CA information 
000x_cert.pem - the cert which will match the PubKey of the cert
```

I used the 000x_cert.pem for my app bundle. So every time i renewed the certificate i could hit the server even though i dont replace the 000x_cert.pem in the app. It works as the public key will be same. Thanks.